# TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher and SQL server

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

Is there any relation between `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` cipher and SQL Server?

When `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` is disabled, ASP.NET application cannot connect to SQL Server. Although SQL Server is still running, SQL Server Management Studio also cannot connect to database. The following error is shown in SSMS.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Answer (score 0):

Read [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server), identify the SQL Server version you use, download and apply the relevant components from the article linked, try again:

> Use the following table to determine whether your current version of SQL Server already has support for TLS 1.2 or whether you have to download an update to enable TLS 1.2 support. Use the download links in the table to obtain the server updates that are applicable to your environment.

Comment: We are using SQL 2012 SP3. It supports TLS1.2. And SQL server is running. Only unable to connect from .net application (.net 4.6) and SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of TLS 1.0 being phased out, we're starting to implement additional security on our servers. Primarily, explicitly disabling TLS 1.0 client and server (and SSL 1/2/3), and explicitly enabling TLS 1.2 and 1.1. In addition, we're restricting the ciphers available for use when connecting over TLS 1.2/1.1.

We followed the article Remus posted to the letter (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server), and used additional resources to ensure we weren't missing anything (this was a good one: https: //blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/tls-1-2-support-read-first/). We also forced .NET Framework to use TLS 1.2->1.1->1.0 search order by adding the SchUseStrongCrypto registry keys on our servers (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/2960358.aspx).

Despite the above, we were unable to connect to SQL 2014 or SQL 2016 instances on a Windows Server 2016 environment when attempting to connect from a Windows Server 2012 R2 environment. We had a SharePoint installation in Windows 2012 R2 that was unable to connect to its database, and we were unable to connect to the instances with SSMS on this same server. Connecting via SSMS from a Windows 10 or another Server 2016 installation worked. Here's the error we were getting:

> sql server Error Number: 10054 Severity: 20 State: 0
>
> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 – An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Once we allowed a TLS_RSA cipher for use on both servers, we were able to connect (didn't matter which cipher we used, we used the first one in this list):

> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

I'm unable to find any resource which explicitly states which ciphers are required for communication to SQL Server, I'm assuming the above list isn't comprehensive. I'd like a definitive resource of some sort, but wanted to post this in case it helps someone.